# asp.net check duplicate and insert data to sql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I want to insert are checkbox data. Before data is insert, system need to verify record is exists in database or not. If record already insert, display label with "User already exists". Currently only insert record to sql database is work. I have try some code but it not work for check duplicate

```
protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string _connStr = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=UniKL;Integrated Security=True";
        string _query = "Insert Into [UniKL].[dbo].[table](id, IDcard, name) VALUES (@id, @IDcard, @name)";
        foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in gvADList.Rows)
        {
            //Find checkbox control in gridview for particular row
            CheckBox cbSelect = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("cbSelect");

            if (cbSelect.Checked)
            {
                string userid = gvrow.Cells[1].Text;
                string name = gvrow.Cells[2].Text;
                string idcard = gvrow.Cells[3].Text;
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        comm.Connection = conn;
                        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        comm.CommandText = _query;
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", userid);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
                        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDcard", idcard);
                        try
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        catch (SqlException ex)
                        {
                            lblMsgLuqman.Text = "Insert data error";
                        }

                        lblMsgLuqman.Text = "Details Inserted Successfully";
                    }
```

Comment: What is _not working_ exactly? You get any exception or error message? Can you please be more specific about your problem?

Comment: Can you show your sql query

Comment: Your probably need a unique constrain on user id column

Comment: you need a good query

Comment: @SonerGönül: no error msg, but I cannot check or verify duplicate record before insert.

Comment: @Izzy: I already update my code with query above. TQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply **Unique** Key Constraint on the field in table where you want to check the Uniqueness.

When you do that and if the Record already exist then the ExecuteNonQuery() function will return **0** to you that is different value than the value after successful insertion**(Number of rows affected)**. I think you can then check the return vale and show the message accordingly.

Hope this helps.